# To understand queries in PHP PG -prepared statemens

Tags: php, postgresql

**How do you read the following code about `pg_query_params` and `pg_prepare`?**

```
$result = pg_query_params ( $dbconn,        
    "SELECT flagged_for_moderator_removal           // unsure about Repetition here
    FROM questions 
    WHERE question_id = $1",
    array ( $_GET['question_id'] ) );

if ( pg_num_rows ( $result ) == 0 ) { 
    $result = pg_prepare ( $dbconn, "get_flagged_status_list",    
        "SELECT flagged_for_moderator_removal       // unsure about Repetition here
        FROM questions 
        WHERE question_id = $1"
    );  
}
```

This question is related to [my thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315378/checking-if-pgprepare-exists) where I do not want to declare twice the prepared statement.

The difference between statements is that the other has a name *get_flagged_status_list*, while the other one does not. I understand the code as follows

```
Iteration |  1                     2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
           run pg_query_params    run pg_qeury_params
           run pg_prepare         
           run pg_execute         run pg_execute
```

However, this is not true, since the code runs `pg_prepare` in the second iteration too.
 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your posted example does not make sense - `pg_prepare()` and `pg_query_params()` are independent functions with different purposes that you would not normally use in conjunction.

`pg_prepare()` prepares a statement (a query) for later execution via `pg_execute()`. This is done as an potential optimization - if you know in advance that you will need to execute the statement many times in a row, preparing it upfront can save some work on the database server, since it does not have to (re-)prepare the statement for each call.

`pg_query_params()` (as well as its 'simpler' version `pg_query()`) just executes the statement (query) directly, forcing the database server to (re)prepare the statement each time the function gets called.

So in short, this

```
$result = pg_query_params($query, $params);
```

will give you the exact same result as this

```
$statement = pg_prepare($query);
$result = pg_execute($statement, $params);
```

The only difference is that in the second case, you still have the prepared statement, ready to reuse for more calls to `pg_execute()` - which is why you can give it a name, since that way you can have different prepared statements on the same connection that you can execute as you please, many times, in arbitrary order.

Comment: I have the `pg_prepare` inside a function. **How can you restrict the re-declaration of the prepared statement?** - I obviously need to remove the *pg_query_params*.

Comment: If it is inside a function, either move the pg_prepare call outside the function (and remove pg_query_param), or just remove the pg_prepare call and use only pg_query_param. Is there a reason why you want to use pg_prepare? It smells like premature optimization.