# pg_query_params and partial index

Tags: php, postgresql, indexing

Using `PHP 5.3.10` against a (quite old) `PostgreSQL 8.2.23` database.

I am using a query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE status = 1 AND id = 123456;
```

I created a partial index to improve performance :

```
CREATE INDEX i1 ON mytable (id) WHERE status = 1;
```

The problem is, when I use `pg_query_params`, it seems that the partial index is not used (and the query is very slow) :

```
pg_query_params('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE status = $1 AND id = $2', array(1,123456));
```

I test the same PHP code on a `PostgreSLQ 9.1` database and it seems to work well (index used). Unfortunately, I can not upgrade to `9.1` at the moment. The faster workaround for me seems not to use partial index...

Is there any known limitation with `pg_query_params` and partial index over old versions of PG ?
Do I have a workaround other than avoiding partial index when using `pg_query_params` ?

**EDIT :**

Here is the execution plan, on 8.2.23 server and 9.1.2 server.
The query executed (by PHP) was :

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE status = $1 AND id = $2
```

BUT, strange behaviour, when really executing the query (I mean removing "EXPLAIN ANALYZE") on PG 9.1 using pg_prepare, the query does not seem to use index (symptom : very slow query, a few seconds... like a seq scan!?).

**PG 8.2, using pg_query_params :**

```
Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..289976.55 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=851.956..3112.038 rows=1 loops=1)
```

**PG 8.2, using pg_prepare + pg_execute :**

```
Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..289976.55 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=399.486..1595.102 rows=1 loops=1)
```

**PG 9.1, using pg_query_params :**

```
Index Scan using i1 on mytable  (cost=0.00..9.61 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.046..0.047 rows=1 loops=1)
```

**PG 9.1, using pg_prepare + pg_execute :**

```
Index Scan using i1 on mytable  (cost=0.00..9.61 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.043..0.043 rows=1 loops=1)
```

**=> but as I said, the real duration of this last pg_execute on PG 9.1 is 1'860 ms !!**

Comment: Could you post what explain says about your query?

Comment: Well, I have no explain to illustrate the problem, cause when I fulfil the template query (replacing $1 whith value 1 and $2 with whatever integer), the index i1 is effectively used.

I just noticed that when removing the condition "WHERE status = 1" from the index OR when using pg_query instead of pg_query_params, the query is fast (just a few ms, so I supposed that index is used), whereas with partial index and pg_query_params the query takes up to 20 seconds...

Comment: What happens if you pg_prepare it first and then run pq_execute?

Comment: with pg_prepare + pg_execute, it is slow (no index plan), on 8.2 and on 9.1. Whereas with pg_query_params I have different behaviour on 8.2 and 9.1... (fast on 9.1 => index scan)

Comment: Still no idea, but what if you run EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ... instead of your plain query?  Do you receive something meaningful?

Comment: just added the result of explain analyze in the original post... but nothing really meaningful

Comment: I wanted to mean passing explain analyze through PHP, sorry.

Comment: Oh yes of course, sorry. I put the EXPLAIN ANALYZE through PHP in my post... BUT, something really strange, on PG 9.1, the pg_execute of EXPLAIN ANALYZE is fast (using i1 index), but when executing the query (still through PHP), it takes much longer (near 2 seconds). The others EXPLAIN ANALYZE (PG 8.2 and PG 9.1+p_query_params) are coherent though...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a prepared statement is that during preparing, it has no idea what values could come in later on. The index conditions says WHERE status = 1, but will the query has a "status=1" value? Hard to predict.

For a query like this, using a prepared statement, an index on both conditions could be the best performance option:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_id_status ON mytable (id, status);
```

This works in version 8.2 and 9.1 as well.

Comment: Ok, but pg_query_params is NOT a prepared statement (=> this is pg_prepare/pg_execute). If I execute the pg_query_params on 8.2, it does not uses index plan, but on a 9.1 server, it seems to use an index plan. I tested the same query with pg_prepare, and it seems that it never use the index plan, neither 8.2 nor 9.1 (and that is normal with partial index, as you explained well)

Comment: I don't thinks so. From the manual: "pg_query_params — Submits a command to the server and waits for the result, with the ability to pass parameters separately from the SQL command text.". Check your querylog to see the SQL statement that gets sent (and thus prepared). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316830/to-understand-queries-in-php-pg-prepared-statemens

Comment: But so, why is pg_query_params much faster than pg_prepare + pg_execute on PostgreSQL 9.1 ?? In my opinion, pg_query_params is not treated as a prepared statement by the engine...